# css background property not working in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, background-color

My html code is as follows. I tested it with both Chrome and Firefox. In both the browsers the first div's background color is not working.

```css
.box-orange {
  // without any position declaration    
  background: orange;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box-red {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box-orange"></div>
  <div class="box-red"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone tell me where is the issue?

Comment: Use this `/* without any position declaration */` instead of `// without any position declaration`. It will work

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the comment, its what is causing the error
comments in css code should be like this `/*your comment*/`

Comment: I'm glad it is, you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use double forward slashes (//) to comment in CSS.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.box-orange {        /* without any position declaration */
  background: orange;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px; 
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.box-red {    
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px; 
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>  
   <div class="box-orange"></div>         
   <div class="box-red"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment is causing you the error. Try read through following link.

[Comments in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/comments-in-css/)